# Filter XDocument more efficiently

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I would like to filter with high performance XML elements from an XML document.

Take for instance this XML file with contacts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="asistentes.xslt"?>
<contactlist evento="Cena Navidad 2010" empresa="company">
  <contact type="1" id="1">
    <name>Name1</name>
    <email>xxxx@zzzz.es</email>
    <confirmado>SI</confirmado>
  </contact>
  <contact type="1" id="2">
    <name>Name2</name>
    <email>xxxxxxxxx@zzzze.es</email>
    <confirmado>Sin confirmar</confirmado>
  </contact>
</contaclist>
```

My current code to filter from this XML document:

```
using System; 
using System.Xml.Linq; 

class Test 
{ 
   static void Main() 
   { 
      string xml = @" the xml above"; 
      XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); 

      foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("contact")) {
         Console.WriteLine(element);
         var id = element.Attribute("id").Value;
         var valor = element.Descendants("confirmado").ToList()[0].Value;
         var email = element.Descendants("email").ToList()[0].Value;
         var name = element.Descendants("name").ToList()[0].Value;
         if (valor.ToString() == "SI") { }
      }
   } 
}
```

What would be the best way to optimize this code to filter on `<confirmado>` element content?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); 

var query = from contact in doc.Root.Elements("contact")
            let confirmado = (string)contact.Element("confirmado")
            where confirmado == "SI"
            select new
            {
                Id    = (int)contact.Attribute("id"),
                Name  = (string)contact.Element("name"),
                Email = (string)contact.Element("email"),
                Valor = confirmado
            };

foreach (var contact in query)
{
    ...
}
```

Points of interest:

- `doc.Root.Elements("contact")` selects only the `<contact>` elements in the document root, instead of searching the whole document for `<contact>` elements.
- The [XElement.Element method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) returns the first child element with the given name. No need to convert the child elements to a list and take the first element.
- The [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) and [XAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) classes provide a wide selection of [convenient conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx).

Comment: the query doesn't get results :'( the problem perhaps is the file not xml fully, is XSLT with <?xml, <?xml-stylesheet, and node contactlist.

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("contact").Where(c => c.Element("confirmado").Value == "SI"))
```